# Rails - Send Twilio messages for custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sms, twilio

In rails 4.2.4, I am using `gem 'twilio-ruby'` to send SMS. Right now I am calling this twilio method for particular action, eg: send otp message & it is working fine. But the issue is same message will send when I am calling other actions.

In development.rb

```
config.middleware.use Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token, '/voice'
```

In user model,

```
def send_otp_notification
  begin
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token
    message = client.messages.create :from=> '+12015598867', :to=>"+#{self.mobile_number}", :body=> "Verify your otp: #{self.otp}"
  rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
    puts "e = #{e}".red
  end
end
```

In mobile/api/user.rb,

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
user.save
user.send_otp_notification
```

Here, `send_otp_notification` method will call only once when user registers, right now when a user creates any other object(eg: create 'posts' table entry) then also otp message will send, how can I avoid this?

Comment: What's the rest of the `mobile/user/api.rb` file? The context would be really useful. It does sound like you're using an `after_save` callback, but I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Using Active Record new_record

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
user.save
tmp = true
user.send_otp_notification if tmp.present?
```

[Active Record Persistence new_record](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F)

hope this solve your issue!!!

Comment: But after save `user.new_record?` will return false, in this case even user will not get a message for the first time also.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord` has two callback method `after_save` or `after_create`.You can use any one or both to call your function dynamically.You need to set those method in your model.No need to set condition or call at anywhere.

```
after_save :send_otp_notification

after_create :send_otp_notification
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your model to contain a `boolean` field that tells if a notification has already been sent for this user

```
class AddOtpSentToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :otp_sent, :boolean, default: false
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :otp_sent
  end
end
```

And modify your function to be flexible in sending otp if it is requested to be sent again or for the first time

```
def send_otp_notification send_again = false
  if !self.otp_sent || send_again
    begin
      client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token
      message = client.messages.create :from=> '+12015598867', :to=>"+#{self.mobile_number}", :body=> "Verify your otp: #{self.otp}"
    rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
      puts "e = #{e}".red
    end
  end
end
```